# Can I delete /var/mail/root?

Tags: 16.04, mail

I got the Message:

```
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
```

Can I delete this file without any problems?

```
/var/mail/root
```

Comment: I wouldn't delete anything that contains "root".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily a good idea. `/var/mail/root` contains email messages that some process on your system tried to bring to the attention of `root`, the system administrator. Read the messages.

If you delete `/var/mail/root`, you will lose all these messages, and `/var/mail/root` will be created anew the next time there's a message.

Comment: This is an Ubuntu on an own Root-Server. I found some errors in that file, but don't they come again if i delete that file. And i have seen, that errors come every 30 min.